# Block Positon changes after changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a X-O game
so html is this:

```js
    const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block")
    let turn =  "X"
    for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.innerHTML == "") {
                this.innerHTML = turn
            }}
        )}
```

```css
    .block {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
}
    #game{
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

And every thing is OK.
But when I press a block it's position changes a little bit:
[image]

Comment: Specify a `vertical-align` for these divs.

Comment: Aside from the problem you will get errors from that code.

Comment: You can right click an element, then click "Inspect element" or similar. You can see in the browser's developer tools with CSS moves your elements around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a slightly different solution using rows and column structure and flex.

Divide the structure into a tabular structure (ex: row, column). Try using `display:flex` to display the boxes in the same line.

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".col");
let turn =  "X";
for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (this.innerHTML == "") {
            this.innerHTML = turn;
        }
    });
 }
```

```css
.row{
    display: flex;
}
.col {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
}
#game {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `inline-block` for your blocks, you could use a **flex** (`display: flex`) and **wrapped** (`flex-wrap: wrap`) container with fixed width and height for your `#game` div.

Using `flex-wrap` saves you from manually splitting your rows.

> `display: flex`, by default, set `flex-direction` to `row`.
> Using `flex-wrap: wrap`, if the content horizontally exceeds the width of the container, it is wrapped.

> In our case, the container has dimention `400px`, so we will get 3 element per row (since every block has `width: 100px`).

*As in this runnable example*

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block")
let turn = "X"
for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
  blocks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.innerHTML == "") {
      this.innerHTML = turn
    }
  })
}
```

```css
#game {
  /* Flex Wrapped Container*/ 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* Dimensions */
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px; /* margin for some gap between boxes */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```